# Custom type not saving in application settings

Tags: c#, application-settings

I have the class `CaptureResolution` representing the resolution for a camera capture:

```
[Serializable]
[SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)]
[XmlRoot (ElementName = "CaptureResolution", IsNullable = false)]
public class CaptureResolution: ApplicationSettingsBase
{
    [UserScopedSetting]
    [SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)]
    [XmlAttribute (AttributeName = "Width")]
    public int Width { get; set; }

    [UserScopedSetting]
    [SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)]
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Height")]
    public int Height { get; set; }

    public CaptureResolution(int width, int height)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
    }

    public CaptureResolution(): this(1024, 720)
    {
    }
}
```

I added a setting into the settings designer with the given type:

[image]

However when calling this

```
Properties.Settings.Default.ResolutionSelection = new CaptureResolution(1920, 1080);
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

The setting is not saved in the user settings file:

```
<setting name="ResolutionSelection" serializeAs="Xml">
    <value />
</setting>
```

I can surely verify that the value is assigned to the setting's property. Otherwise the program wouldn't work at all. I also had a look with the debugger on this.

Also I already searched on the internet for suitable solutions but in the end it didn't really helped. Other settings are saved without any problems.

Afaik the settings designer needs a class that can be serialized to XML and a default parameterless constructor that is public accessible. I did both so I'm wondering why it is not working as intended.

**Additional question**

How can I assign a default value to this custom type setting? 
Entering `new FaceDetection.Model.CaptureResolution()` ends up in an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deriving `CaptureResolution` from `ApplicationSettingsBase`:

```
public class CaptureResolution: ApplicationSettingsBase
```

Don't do that. There is no need to do it, and doing so obviously doesn't work.

**Default Value**

The settings desinger will create a `Settings.cs` if you click on the "View Code" button on its top. In this `Settings.cs` file you can add your own code and you can manually create application settings, e.g. something like that:

```
[UserScopedSetting]
public CaptureResolution ResolutionSelection
{
  get
  {
    var value = (CaptureResolution)this[nameof(ResolutionSelection)];
    if (value == null)
    {
      value = new CaptureResolution(1, 2);  // decent default value
      this[nameof(ResolutionSelection)] = value;
    }
    return value;
  }
  set { this[nameof(ResolutionSelection)] = value; }
}
```

This will create a default value it the setting is null. You will have to remove the setting that you created using the desinger.

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm.